# Checking if a link is active from an array

Tags: python, arrays

Hey guys i have an array and i want to check if the websites in the array are active or not.One of the websites in the array is active but the other is not..So to find out i wrote a code like

```
import httplib
i = ['www.nri.com','www.kundis.com']
for b in i:
    c = httplib.HTTPConnection(b)
    c.request("HEAD", '')

if c.getresponse().status == 200:
   print('web site exists')



c2 = httplib.HTTPConnection(b)
c2.request("HEAD",'')

if c2.getresponse().status == 302:
   print('website not exists')
```

When i run this code it only prints `website not exists`. But when i used `i[0] and i[1]` instead of b in  `httplib.HTTPConnection()` it works.

Can you guys tell me why its happening ??..How can i make it right by giving `b` as a parameter in `httplib.HTTPConnection()`.Thanx for the help

Comment: You might need the full URL including the `http://` part

Comment: None of your links give 200 for me , both give 301 and 302 respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
if c.getresponse().status == 200:
   print('web site exists')
```

part is outside your `for` loop, so it only checks the status code of the *last* url you called inside your `for` loop.

---

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
import httplib
i = ['www.nri.com','www.kundis.com']
for b in i:

    print('Checking ' + b)

    c = httplib.HTTPConnection(b)
    c.request("HEAD", '')

    if c.getresponse().status == 200:
        print('web site exists')

    if c.getresponse().status == 302:
        print('website not exists')
```

Comment: It should be noted running his code using `requests` I get a `200` from both sites. One seems to be a "Buy this Domain" page but it's still going to return a 200.

Comment: woah exactly..thanx buddy